# Eclipse won't run Android app until I click Run a few times, no feedback or status information

Tags: android, eclipse, feedback

I've started Android Development and I'm using Eclipse for the first time in years, coming from a Visual Studio background. When I click Run in Visual Studio I begin to get feedback immediately. Using Eclipse however, I get very little feedback and it's only after a few clicks of the run button.

It normally takes a few minutes for the app to run after making even only the littlest changes to the UI XML, and I will see nothing in the LogCat or Console tabs. I'll click run.... nothing, click run again after a few minutes.... nothing, click it again after a few minutes.... and finally it'll give me some feedback that it's launching the app.

Is there any way to improve the responsiveness / feedback I'm getting?

Comment: How did You test it? With emulator or real device? By testing it with the AVD emulator, it will take a long time.

Comment: Yeah, it's with the AVD emulator. Is there any way for me to see *any* feedback so I know if it's working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah....just waiting. You don´t have to push the run button many times. I would be happy if there where another solution, but fact is, that the emulator is terrifying slow. Even this depends on the properties from which You created your AVD. There are some setting when creating a new one, internal storage and ram size. The lower these values are the faster it creates an emulator. This depends on what You need, if You don´t need sd card storage, disable it. If you don´t need much ram size, set the minimum. Even there are some tricks to speed up a little bit:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

It seems that there is a faster alternative emulator, but I hadn´t tried it:

http://enisgeeks.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/an-amazing-alternative-to-android-emulator/